# Dynamic "add another product" form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a dynamic form that has inputs and selects. The select values will come from a JSON data (for now, I'm just using an array) and it has to have the feature to "add another product".

One single page must have two forms, with same functionality

When clicking "Add another product" I clone a row, that it was supposed to be cloned on the parent form, but this is nos happening and can't get why.

I leave a [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWBrpX) with the same code as below

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Dynamic Select</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="" class="dynamic-select">
    <div class="main-clone">
        <select name="myName">
                <option value="">Hi</option>
        </select>
        <input name="myText" type="text">
    </div>
    <p class="clone-btn">Add another product</p>
    <p class="re">Re</p>
</form>

<form id="myForm2" action="" class="dynamic-select">
    <div class="main-clone">
        <select name="myName">
                <option value="">Hi</option>
        </select>
        <input name="myText" type="text">
    </div>
    <p class="clone-btn">Add another product</p>
    <p class="re">Re</p>
</form>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

jQuery FORM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = ['Juanma', 'Pepe', 'Esteban', 'Pedro', 'Juan'];
    var arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    dynamicSelect.init(arr,'#myForm');
    dynamicSelect.init(arr,'#myForm2');

    $('form').on('click','.delete-clone', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

});

var dynamicSelect = {
    init: function(arr,id){
        this.cachedDom(id);
        this.bindEvents();
        this.createElement(arr);
    },
    cachedDom : function(id){
        this.$form = $(id);
        this.$select = this.$form.find('select');
        this.$mainClone = this.$form.find(".main-clone");
        this.$cloneBtn = this.$form.find('.clone-btn');
        this.$submit = this.$form.find('.re');
    },
    bindEvents : function(){
        this.$cloneBtn.on('click', this.cloneElement.bind(this));
        this.$submit.on('click', this.getValues.bind(this));
    },
    createElement: function(arr){
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        arr.forEach(function(arr, index) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = arr;
            opt.value = arr;
            fragment.appendChild(opt);
        });
        this.$select.append(fragment);
    },
    cloneElement: function(){
        var $clone = this.$mainClone.clone();
        $clone.append('<span class="delete-clone">X</span>');
        $clone.insertAfter(this.$mainClone);
    },
    getValues: function(){
        console.log(this.$form.serialize());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is you are not instantiating the object, so the last item in your code will be the one to inherit all the properties - which is why only the 2nd form is being activated properly inheriting the correct "this" for each bind.

What you need to do is this:

```
var test = Object.create(dynamicSelect);
var test2 = Object.create(dynamicSelect);
test.init(arr,'#myForm');
test2.init(arr,'#myForm2');
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmZBGY?editors=1010

This essentially makes each object have its own "this" when the object is instantiated. In other languages or es6 that have actual classes, you would see something like class Dog {}. Then you would have:

```
class Dog {
 bark(){
 }
}    
const fido = new dog();
fido.bark();
```

This does the same thing as object.create for the most part.